# Sending 'MKOverlayView to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKOverlay>'

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkoverlay

I'm getting the following warning when adding overlays to my map view:

```
Sending 'MKOverlayView *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<MKOverlay>'
```

The code works great, and the overlays are drawn as they should, but I would love to get rid of the warning.
The code that's causing it:

```
for(MKOverlayView *overlay in [mapView overlays]) {
    [mapView removeOverlay:overlay];
}
```

(Obviously, the line inside the for loop is what's raising this error)
Google doesn't have a single result for that error. only similar with MKAnnotationView for example.
The solutions there (for example):

```
for(id<MKOverlay> *overlay in [mapView overlays]) {
    [mapView removeOverlay:overlay];
}
```

raises an error.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `overlays` property returns an array of the overlay *model* objects (the objects that conform to the `MKOverlay` protocol) and not the overlay *views*.

So change the for-loop to:

```
for(id<MKOverlay> overlay in [mapView overlays]) {
```

Note there is no asterisk in the `id<MKOverlay> overlay` part.

Comment: I missed the asterisk part.. I will check it tomorrow when I got back to a Mac. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yup. There's no star because type `id` (with or without protocol qualifiers) is implicitly a pointer.